# Send User class objects from controller to view in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm Using rapid authentication to login users,I need to this that after login user send User Class objects to view my code is here:

```
  use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

How I Can send User class objects inside Home?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use auth user to get user object

```
Auth::user()
```

Auth:user() will return user object.you can use it any view and controller or model

if you want acccess id from user in your blade template

```
{{isset( Auth::user()->id)? Auth::user()->id:''}}
```

Comment: for example in this code `{{$user->name}}` to give user name in foreach where I Can use ?

Comment: {{Auth::user()->name }}

Comment: How I Can use this in foreach?

Comment: you dont foreach since you need authenticated user detail.you can access all detail from Auth:user()

Comment: when I login as admin I want give all users from database I used this code `@foreach($users as $user)`Now How I Can this with Auth?I am admin

Comment: one think is you need to override login method or you can write query in blade like  <?php $users=User::all(); ?>